# How to use Orderby and Order HTML Code?

Tags: html

There is this HTML code i am very not familiar with and want to edit for a product list and specifically i want to edit the items by order they appear in the array.

The only edits I can create are through changing the order field with asc and dec, what other inputs can i  use to change the order to match the products id list as listed? and what does the field in order represent?

`div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 50px;">[products ids="476,466,456,444,243,409,404,399,230,219,211" orderby="date" order="dec"]`

Comment: The specific edits you wish to put through are not in HTML, this looks like serverside code, what are you using on the back end?

Comment: I believe this is Woocommerce on Wordpress. Is there a FAQ for this?

Comment: I've done a quick search, how about this: https://www.sellwithwp.com/create-woocommerce-custom-product-sorting/

Comment: I think the version of woocommerce is older so the Advanced options in the article isn't available

Comment: ok, i think changing order="custom" will fix it. Thanks!